# Rank of Jordan block

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Let matrix $A=(a_{ij})_{n\times n } $ be such that $a_{ii}=\lambda, 2\leq i \leq n $ and $a_{ii+1}=1, 1\leq i \leq n-1 $ and $a_{ij}=0$ if $j\not\in \{1,i, i+1\}$ so basically A is nearly a Jordan block of degree n with eigenvalue $\lambda $ except for the first column. 
Is it possible to show that $$\text{rank} (A-\lambda I_n)=n-1 $$?

Comment: You haven't said nothing about the first column... If the last entry of that column is non-zero, then the matrix has full rank.

Comment: Basically I'm trying to describe a matrix that is a Jordan block except it's first column is changed.

Comment: _What is the first column_? How is it "changed"?

Comment: Just meaning that the first column could be anything with entries say $a_{11}, a_{21},...,a_{n1} $.

Comment: Ah ok. Then my first comment gives an answer.

Comment: Actually, $A-\lambda I$ has full rank _if and only if_ the last entry of the first column is non-zero.

Comment: Note that the columns $2,\ldots,n$ of $A-\lambda I$ are the standard basis vectors $e_1,\ldots,e_{n-1}$.